# can't add custom js files to wpbootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

https://github.com/320press/wordpress-bootstrap

How do I add custom.js to this theme? I'm not very good at gruntjs. Let's say it's path is `library/js/custom.js`

Here's the gruntfile: https://github.com/320press/wordpress-bootstrap/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use `enqueue` to embed script into your theme. Create a function in `function.php` file as

```
/**
*Enqueue styles.
*/

function add_scripts() {

wp_register_script( 'customScript', get_template_directory_uri() . 'library/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
// here it is just example of path. you can use yours.
wp_enqueue_script( 'customScript' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```